# Brightness hotkeys not working on linux mint 15 (HP mini 210-4000)

Tags: linux-mint, hotkeys, brightness

I have linuxmint 15 Mate running on my netbook(HP mini 210-4000). All hotkeys are working fine except the brightness ones. Slider do pops up on pressing the keys but brightness doesn't change at all. The brightness is set to 100%. None of the solutions worked for me. Please anyone help me with this.

Comment: None of which solutions didn't work for you. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I added `acpi_osi= ( "quit splash acpi_osi="  )` to Grub and this helped my Acer 5742z with Intel graphics, give it a try and see if it works, good luck.

Note that the slider will not pop up on pressing the keys but brightness does change.